# Amavis spamassassin per-user configuration without using a database

Tags: spamassassin, amavis

Is it possible to configure amavisd-new to let a **per-user configuration** for spamassassin without using a DBMS?
I have a home directory for each user and would like to store their SA preferences and baesian data on their *~/.spamassassin* dir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that in Amavisd and SpamAssassin combo. You need additional method (ex procmail) for delivering email to SpamAssassin.

Excerpt from [old archive of SpamAssassin-users mailing list](http://marc.info/?t=108068766500001&r=1&w=2),  "Vermyndax" wrote

> Amavisd-New ignores a lot of the options in *local.cf* and ignores all of
>   the *user_prefs* files except for its own.
>
> See: [this FAQ](http://www.ijs.si/software/amavisd/#faq-spam)
>
> I wanted the same control, so I separated spamassassin from amavisd-new completely and only use it for virus scanning.  I then use procmail delivery for SA to implement this functionality.